# What new technologies should I learn for Web Development?

Tags: language-agnostic

I want to increase my skills in web development. I have already picked up a book on JQuery and Entity Framework. Is their anything else I should read up on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The MVC Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) is the best thing going for web dev these days. Ruby on Rails and ASP.NET MVC are both implementations of the pattern. Learning the concepts will be useful on either platform.

Get Firebug if you don't already have it.  It will save you a lot of pain and suffering.

Comment: @Jason: +1 for firebug really change ajax development!!!

Comment: The Firebug equivalent for IE browsers should be of great help: http://ejohn.org/blog/deep-tracing-of-internet-explorer/

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you've decided on the MS Stack, so I'll stay within that.

If you want to do Internet work, I'd say read up on ASP.net MVC2 Beta (good starting place would be http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/17/asp.net-mvc-2-beta-released.aspx).

If you want to do internal IT sites, I'd say hit SharePoint. It is built on ASP.net WebForms and seems to be really taking off.

That is how the market SEEMS to be breaking down at the moment, not me saying "you should only do MVC on the web and SharePoint for corporate work". You can use either, I'm just suggesting where I think you'll find the most jobs...

I'd recommend Linq if you haven't worked with it yet. You can get a lot of mileage out of Linq. Linq To Entities (for Entity Framework), Linq To SQL (if you don't like EF), Linq to XML, Linq to Objects, heck even Linq To Flickr.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already I'd also get yourself up to speed using an **Inversion of Control** container. (Castle Windsor for instance).

Answer (score 0):

I would say [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and [pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_(computer_science)), also I don't know in which language you are programming but a [cookbook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596100636) for that language would be good also.

Answer (score 0):

You should pay a visit to the [Mix09](http://videos.visitmix.com/MIX09/) website. It has lots of cool videos of new and hot (Microsoft) technologies.

Also, I recommend you have a look at [ASP.Net MVC](http://www.asp.net/mVC/).

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to take a look at the opensource MVC projects.
Eg. 
[NerdDinner](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/)

A lot more dot net open source projects can be found at that site (codeplex), that contain interesting MVC and other (entity, Silverlight, ...) sources.

And my last tip would be,
It's better to be very good at one programming language, than to have basic knowledge of 3 programming languages :)

Keep learning!

Answer (score 0):

You must have

1. A good server side platform I will advice "Ruby On Rails"
2. Strong Javascript knowledge and one good js library Jquery is great
3. One ORM tool. With rails it is activeRecord. if you choose .Net then Entity FrameWork or Nhibernate is good.
4. Final and most important point you must have a very good knowledge of Http protocol . I will suggest this book 
   [http://www.amazon.com/HTTP-Definitive-Guide-David-Gourley/dp/1565925092](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565925092)
5. Be familiar with some enterprise patterns http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/